# perform validation or raise exception for incorrect user input in mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, validation, csv

I'm trying to perform validation in Crud operations in MySQL. My table has name,idno,division and I have wrote the MySQL output into a csv file. I'm giving a user input and if the user input matches with the idno in table then it should print the entire row.
This works fine when I give the idno in the table but it doesn't raises exception when an incorrect value is given as input. Can anyone help me with raising exception or performing validation?

Here are my codes:

def search (self):

```
try:

    with open("test.csv", 'rb') as inputfile:

        reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile)
        user_input=int(raw_input("Enter the Idno to search:"))
        rows = [row for row in reader if row['Idno']==str(int(user_input)

        for row in rows:
            print rows


except ValueError:
    print "Enter correct idno "
```

search()

Answer (score 0):

Here, to validate your user input from `raw_input` you can consider two ways
    - checking your value with regular expression
    - Checking with the actual database idno.

for example, before fetching actual data from database, check whether given idno is available or not using select query

Query: `select idno from <table_name>`
and check for the existence. If not available, you can raise value error
 exception : `raise ValueError`

Comment: I'm trying to validate user input with the idno in either csv or mysql database. I mean is it possible to validate user input after its inserted into table. Validating through csv doesnt raises exception for incorrect values

Comment: Since it is a validation part from our side and not a part of either default error check or defined error, you need to manually raise error if you did not find value. or, try creating user defined exception class and raise that

Comment: Can you help me by explaining your last comment with an example?

Comment: I know that I have to raise exceptions manually but I don't know how to do them

Comment: To through error: you can have raise after for loop. for example: `for row in rows: print rows else: raise ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

I take it that this line posted in your question

```
rows =  rows = [row for row in reader if row['Idno'] == str(int(user_input)
```

should really be

```
rows = [row for row in reader if row['Idno'] == str(int(user_input))]
```

You are checking this for a `ValueError`. Your exception will trap situations where the user inputs a value that is not an integer. But I take it that for an id number to be valid, it must also appear in your `.csv` file. Your code doesn't test for that. You need something like

```
rows = [row for row in reader if row['Idno'] == str(int(user_input))]
if not rows:
    raise ValueError("idno %r not found")
```

Or if, as your comments suggest, you have an objection to checking if the list is empty:

```
rows = [row for row in reader if row['Idno'] == str(int(user_input))]
if user_input not in rows:
    raise ValueError("idno %r not found")
```

Comment: rows was a typo. sorry

Comment: Ur command doesnt prints any output even if user input is given with table value

Comment: That is because your code doesn't have a `print` statement and your function doesn't return a value. Your stated problem was that invalid input was not trapped, not that valid input didn't do what you expect. In fact you said it did do what you expect. I assumed you left out the other stuff as irrelevant to your question.

Comment: And my response remains the same. After your code creates the list `rows` it should check to see if the list is empty. If it is, it should raise an exception that will be trapped in your `ValueError` exception handler lower down.

Comment: I tried this but its not printing any output for correct and incorrect user input...                    rows = [row for row in reader if row['Idno'] == str(int(user_input))]

            if rows==user_input:
                for row in rows:
                    print row
                    
            else:
               print ("idno not found")

Comment: `rows` will never be equal to user_input because `rows` is a list and `user_input` is a string.

Comment: ya but i can check whether string is present in list or not and if its not available i can raise exceptions right?

Comment: Sure. That is another way to do it. But checking if your value is in the list and checking if the list is empty will generally do the same thing. If the id number is unique (which, given the name, I would expect) then the list will either be empty or contain the one value you are looking for.

Comment: You say "I can check whether string is present in list or not". You can. But `if rows==user_input` doesn't check to see if `user_input` is in `rows`. It checks to see if `user_input` a list that has the same elements as `rows`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to perform validation using MySQL db and it works. But I dont know what should replace if result==() to make it more meaningful and perfect as () None doesn't works for me.

```
def search(self):

        user_input=raw_input('Enter idno:')

        cursor.execute("select * from table where Idno='{0}';".format(user_input))
        result=cursor.fetchall()

        if result==():
            print "User_input didnt match"

        else:
            print result
search()
```